# Class attribute defined as a length of another List Type class attribute doesn't update itself and always returns the same value

Tags: python, oop, playing-cards, class-attributes

I'm writing a code for the card game 'War'. While defining a "Deck" class, I've defined an attribute "self.cards" which gives the list of all the cards currently in a deck of cards. I've also defined an attribute "self.length" which is expected to give the length of the "self.cards" attribute.

BUT, when I use **the expression `deck.length`, it returns a fixed value**, which doesn't change even when the cards in the deck ("self.cards") are removed/added. On the other hand when I use **the expression `len(deck.cards)`, it returns the desired output** (that is the updated size of the deck).

**The code is:**

```py
# I've used only two suits and three ranks to explain this problem

suits = ('Hearts','Spades')
ranks = ('Queen','King','Ace')

class Card():
    
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

class Deck():
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Create an empty deck and fill it with the available cards
        self.cards = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.cards.append(Card(suit,rank))
        
        self.length = len(self.cards)

    def deal_top_card (self):
        self.cards.pop(0)

deck = Deck()
# Removing Three cards one after the other
deck.deal_top_card()
deck.deal_top_card()
deck.deal_top_card()
print(f"Length according to length attribute = {deck.length}")
print(f"Length of the list of cards = {len(deck.cards)}")
```

The output of the code above is:

```
Length according to length attribute = 6
Length of the list of cards = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `length` is a mere attribute. That means that it receives a value when it is defined, and keeps that value until it is assigned again.

But Python has a concept that does what you want with properties:

```
class Deck():
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Create an empty deck and fill it with the available cards
        self.cards = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.cards.append(Card(suit,rank))
        
    @property
    def length(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def deal_top_card (self):
        self.cards.pop(0)
```

A property is used as a special member that actually executes a method each time it is used. You can now successfully use:

```
deck = Deck()
# Removing Three cards one after the other
deck.deal_top_card()
deck.deal_top_card()
deck.deal_top_card()
print(f"Length according to length attribute = {deck.length}")
print(f"Length of the list of cards = {len(deck.cards)}")
```

and get as expected:

```
Length according to length attribute = 3
Length of the list of cards = 3
```

BTW, properties are even more powerful that that and can call other methods when assigned to or deleted. Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property for more...

Answer (score 0):

You are only updating the self.length in the init() method. So its not updating itself every time you pop a card. Init is only called once, when you create the object. You should add this:

```
def deal_top_card (self):
    self.cards.pop(0)
    self.length = len(self.cards)
```

To update length every time you pop a card

Answer (score 0):

At attribute won't update itself. It looks like you want a property or a method.

A property is something you want to use if you want to access `length` as if it were an attribute. It could also allow you to control what happens if some code wants to override the value of length:

```
class Deck:
    ....
    @property
    def length(self):
        return len(self.cards)

...
print(f"Length according to length property = {deck.length}")
```

a method is similar, but you call it explicitly:

```
class Deck:
    ....
    
    def length(self):
        return len(self.cards)

...
print(f"Length according to length method = {deck.length()}")
```

Finally, you can define the magic `__len__` and just call `len(deck)`, since the concept of length is applicable to many types in Python.

Further, you might consider that a `Deck` is a concept so similar to "a sequence of cards" that it might make sense to make it a subclass of `list`, in which case you wouldn't need to define the length method at all.